# How to get the inner error message of a trigger or action from a workflow with kusto

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, kusto-explorer

I want to create a report with all failed workflows. Also I need to retrieve the statusCode, error message and innerError when a trigger or action failed in each failed worklfow Apps through a kusto query. The image below shows an example of the information what I wanted to retrieve in my report from a failed trigger:

[image]

My current kusto query is:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where Category == "WorkflowRuntime"
| where status_s  == "Failed"
| extend ResourceName = coalesce(resource_actionName_s, resource_triggerName_s)
| extend ErrorMessage = strcat(code_s, iif(error_message_s == '','',' '),iif(error_message_s == '','',split(error_message_s,'.')[0]))
| project
    LogicAppName = resource_workflowName_s,
    ResourceName,
    LogicAppId = resource_runId_s,
    ErrorCode = code_s,
    ErrorMessage
```

However, the variable **code_s** and **error_message_s** from the table **AzureDiagnostics** only retrieve the value: BadRequest. How could I retreived the statuscode, error message and innererror by using a kusto query?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to achieve this through tracked properties. I have set the required values from logic apps through tracked properties and viewing them in my logs using the below Query.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/workflowActionCompleted"
| where status_s == "Failed"
| extend Status = code_s
| project
    LogicAppName = resource_workflowName_s,
    ResourceRunID = resource_runId_s,
    Operation = OperationName,
    ActionName = coalesce(resource_actionName_s, resource_triggerName_s),
    Status,
    StatusCode=trackedProperties_StatusCode_d,
    ConnectorName = trackedProperties_ConnectorName_s,
    ErrorCode = trackedProperties_outputs_error_code_s,
    Message = trackedProperties_outputs_error_message_s
```

Below are the tracked properties in my logic app

[image]

```
ConnectorName:"HTTP"
outputs:"@action()['outputs']['body']"
StatusCode:"@action()['outputs']['statusCode']"
```

**In logs**

[image]

Comment: Hi, tks for your help. How could you add the track properties of a trigger?. When I clicked under Settings of a trigger, I do not know how to set up these values.

Comment: @sergioMoreno, just like key-pair values. In general tracked properties can take references of @ triggerBody, @ action()['inputs'] and @ action()['outputs']. You just need to give the property a name that you are tracking and use any of the above references of the current action. You can also try checking [trackedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#azure-monitor-diagnostics-events)

Comment: Tks for your support. Maybe I did wrote incorrect the question. Let say we have the trigger "When a new email arrives". When I open the settings of this trigger there is no option to track propertities. My question is when a trigger faile, how could I retrieve the innererror of the output of the trigger?.

Comment: @sergioMoreno, Can you help me with what is making your trigger fail? So that I can reproduce the same in my environment and check for alternatives.

Comment: Hi sure tks for your help. I am getting the error 502 - Request failed. Try again later. The trigger is "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox". From the kusto query I got only Bad request and I would like to know how to retrieve this error message and error code.